# Adjust equations in a multicol environment

Tags: equations, multicol, ieeetran

Using the [IEEEtran](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-conference-template/grfzhhncsfqn) document class, and trying to adjust the spacing in 2 equations to fit to 1 row.

My code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Conference Paper Title (IEEEtran)}


\begin{abstract}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
This and the IEEEtran.cls ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
keyword1, keyword2
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\blindtext 

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \noindent
  \begin{equation}
   J_{P_m} = \frac{A_{P_n} - A_{P_m}}{\Delta t}  \label{eq_1}
  \end{equation} \columnbreak
  \begin{equation}
    BR_{P_m} = |bearing(P_n) - bearing(P_m)|  \label{eq_2}
  \end{equation}
\end{multicols}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

No error or warning generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your document is in two-column mode; I can see no reason for swiching into what amounts to four-column mode. Hence, do delete the `multicols` wrapper.

Some additional suggestions. Do consider using a `gather` environment instead of two separate `equation` environments. I would also recommend you load a Times Roman math font package, such as `newtxmath`, to go with the document's Times Roman text font. Finally, use either `\mathrm` (for upright lettering) or `\mathit` (for slanted lettering) of variable names consisting of entire words.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{amsmath,blindtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % Times Roman math font package
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % for typesetting variable names

\begin{document}
\title{Conference Paper Title (IEEEtran)}

\begin{abstract}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
This and the IEEEtran.cls \dots
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
keyword1, keyword2
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\blindtext % don't leave a blank line before display math material
\begin{gather}
   J_{P_m}  = \frac{A_{P_n} - A_{P_m}}{\Delta t}  \label{eq_1} \\
   BR_{P_m} = |\vn{bearing}(P_n) - \vn{bearing}(P_m)|  \label{eq_2}
  \end{gather}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```